# Access struct within struct in different functions

Tags: c, struct

I have nested structs and I'm having trouble assigning values to the inner struct in different functions. My structs are defined as:

```
typedef struct {
    double reading;
    float readingTime;
    int readingNum;
} Measurement;

typedef struct {
    Measurement vref;
    Measurement vout;
    Measurement voutShort; 
} Unit;
```

In the function (`measureUnit()`) where I declare `Unit unit;`I call `takeMeasurement(unit)` (which I simplified for clarity below) and where I try to assign values to some values in the inner Measurement struct :

```
takeMeasurement(Unit unit){
    int readingNum = 42;
    unit.vout.readingNum = readingNum;
}
```

When I then try to access these values in `printData(Unit unit)` which is called from `measureUnit()`,

```
`printf("%i", unit.vout.readingNum)`
```

always prints `0`.

Shouldn't these values "follow" `unit` around through different functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C passes arguments by *value* resulting in the changes being made to `unit` in `takeMeasurement()` being applied to a *copy* of the argument supplied to the function. Pass the address of a `Unit` to the function to ensure changes are visible to the caller:

```
void takeMeasurement(Unit* unit){
    int readingNum = 42;
    unit->vout.readingNum = readingNum;
}
```

To invoke:

```
Unit u = { 0.0 };
takeMeasurement(&u);
```

It is also desirable to pass a pointer to a `const struct` to a function that only reads the values of the `struct` to avoid making a copy of the `struct`, particularly if the `struct` is large:

```
void printData(const Unit* unit)
{
    printf("%i", unit->vout.readingNum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You pass the struct itself to the function, which means you pass a copy of your struct to the function and modify this copy, not the original structure. You might want to pass a pointer to the struct instead:

```
takeMeasurement(Unit* unit){
    int readingNum = 42;
    unit->vout.readingNum = readingNum;
}

// call it something like that
takeMeasurement(&my_unit_struct);
//              ^ this means "the address of my_unit_struct"
```